# scrollIntoView() not working after first render

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

`/routes/[symbol]/+page.ts`:

```js
afterUpdate(() => {
    console.log(
        "from calendar view: symbol:",
        data.symbol,
        data.calendar.months[data.symbol],
        `${new Date().getFullYear()}-${new Date().getMonth() + 1}`
    )

    if (data.calendar.months[data.symbol] != null) {
        let el = document.getElementById(`${new Date().getFullYear()}-${new Date().getMonth() + 1}`)
        console.log("element: ", el)

        el!.scrollIntoView()
    }
})
```

In the initial render, there is a data load that takes place in +layout.ts.  When this happens, the scrollIntoView works fine.  However, if I navigate back to this link, and no data load is necessary, it does not work.  The element is found, and the console.logs happen as expected, but it does not scroll.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with a fix here.

I don't know why, but when going from page a to page b with a link with a fragment (like `b#second-part`), it will play my custom page transition and scroll too far.

So to fix this, I tried something like this :

```js
afterNavigate(() => {
   const hash = $page.url.hash;
   const scrollTo = hash && document.getElementById(hash.slice(1, hash.length));
   if (scrollTo) {
      setTimeout(() => {
         scrollTo.scrollIntoView();
      }, 1000);
   }
});
```

Which only worked just like you, on first render (reloading the page only).

After a bit of debugging, I found that in the `setTimeout` callback function, my `scrollTo` element does not have a `scrollIntoView` function.

A dirty fix would be to just reassign `scrollTo` to `document.getElementById(...)`.

So, in your case, I would put a `setTimeout` and in the callback function reassign `el`.